# How to use window.location.href after a post submission?

Tags: syntax, window.location

I have tried window.location.href without doing any submission it works

```
  window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
```

But how about if I have to do a post submission, then if the data is valid, I would like to perform a redirect using   `window.location.href` Can somebody explain to me how this can be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP you can simply use a header.

```
<?php header("Location: http://google.com"); ?>
```

As for doing the redirect with just JavaScript...

```
<script> window.location = 'http://google.com'; </script>
```